# Need to add "best-practies" to the tag black list

Tags: support, tag-block-request

Just seen the [best-practies](/questions/tagged/best-practies) on Stack Overflow.

I'm in the process of editing to remove it, but it would be great if someone could add it to the black list.

Comment: Do you mean "best-practices"?

Comment: @Mark, I think he means what he wrote...basically he's saying that people are often tagging something incorrectly...it must be a common misspelling, so if it were blacklisted, it might stop people from using it...

Comment: on second thought, i'm probably mistaken, perhaps because people are not allowed to use best-practices, they just use a misspelling of it to get around not being able to use it

Comment: @david - you've got it.